How to run an executable Python script packaged in a wheel?
Suppose I've got a "wheel" file that contains executable python script myscript.py and a few python modules it imports.
Now I want to run myscript.py on a host with python virtual environment "xyz".
So I install the "wheel" file in this virtual environment and then run the script like this:
(xyz)> python ~/xyz/mypackage/mysubpackage/myscript.py

Is it a good practice ? Is it better to run it as: (xyz)> python myscript.py ? How to do it ?

You actually explained how to run the script. Asking if it is good practice makes your question opinion based.

Correct. I should have asked about other options to run a python executable packaged in a wheel ...

If you already package your project into a wheel, look into using the console_script entry point, or alternatively without using that, set it up so that it can be invoked using python -m
